# Display user location on react native maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

How to display user location on React Native Maps

```js
<MapView
    region={this.props.coordinate}
>
    //My map markers
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

set `showsUserLocation` true

```js
<MapView
    region={this.props.coordinate}
    showsUserLocation={true}
  >
    //My map markers
</MapView>
```

Comment: Does showUserLocation set to true handle the scenario when user changes location, or one would have to use navigator.getlocation.watchPosition?

Comment: You can use `followsUserLocation={true}` to enable that.

Comment: this won't jump to user's location though, so you have to use `Location.getCurrentPositionAsync` to get current user location Latitude & Longitude to pass to the `MapView` region and set the lat/longitude delta to zoom an appropriate amount.

Comment: Don't forget to allow permissions to access location

Answer (score 4):

Either you can use property of `MapView` called `showsUserLocation` mentioned [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

Or you can fetch user location using [GeoLocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) and display it on `Marker`

Answer (score 1):

```
<MapView
region={this.props.coordinate}
showsUserLocation={true} >
```